# Query entries posted in the past month

Tags: templating, query

I’m trying to show only entries for the created in the last month. I’ve taken this from the example in [the docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/entries.html#postdate) but it ends up showing nothing. There’s 100% entries with a postDate in the last month.

What am I missing?

```
{% set start = now|date_modify("-1 month")|date('Y-m-d') %}
{% set end = now|date('Y-m-d') %}

{% set newsQuery = craft.entries({
    section: 'news',
    postDate: ['and', ">= #{start}", "< #{end}"],
}) %}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Immediately found a solution!

```
{% set newsQuery = craft.entries({
    section: 'news',
    after: now|date_modify('0:00 -1 months'),
}) %}
```